# What's the best way to handle Eclipse errors on CouchDB Map/Reduce JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

As noted in [Where to write and store mongoDB map/reduce functions in java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095861/where-to-write-and-store-mongodb-map-reduce-functions-in-java-project) - Eclipse doesn't like a JavaScript (`.js`) file to only contain the following:

```
 function(doc) {
   if(doc.somekey) emit(doc._id, doc);
 }
```

The keyword `function` is marked with an error:

> Syntax error on token "function", Identifier expected after this token

This form is used in MapReduce, but perhaps it's not exactly valid JavaScript (I'm not a lawyer). Is there any way to allow this form?

*edit* it looks like it's a function *expression* instead of a function *statement*. ( [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions) )

- **Non-solution:** "Just add a function name" according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/11258388/185799 it seems that it's not important to economize on the size of these functions. However, adding a function name results in: `{"error":"compilation_error","reason":"Compilation of the map function in the 'myView' view failed: Expression does not eval to a function."}`
- Possible solution? Add a function name or "module.exports = " at the top, and then remove it during a build phase, using grunt/gulp/yeoman or something related.
- For now, what I am actually doing is using the literal form `function anonymous(...` and then doing a string replace just before calling `synchronizeWithDb()` to replace `function anonymous(` with `function(`. This doesn't answer my question, but works around it.

Comment: I (like Eclipse) am curious how you could define a single anonymous function in a file all by itself and actually use it that way.  Any anonymous function I've ever used is defined within the context that it is passed to a function or immediately executed so it is never defined by itself.  When done that way, there is no handle by which it can be used somewhere.  If there is more to this file, then please show us the rest of the context around this definition.

Comment: It's a map function as in http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Map_Functions  - I think the distinction here is that it is a function expression instead of a function statement. Perhaps it needs a different file suffix than ".js" !

Comment: .. in other words, it's not used "in a file all by itself". Again, ".js" may be inappropriate here

Comment: Related CouchDB issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1397

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three bad options:

1. You can ignore the error since CouchDB can process this file (it will wrap it later to make it valid).
2. You can change the file extension but then you lose syntax highlight, code completion and error checks.
3. You can delete the error in the error view. It will stay deleted until you change the file the next time or you do a full build.
4. You may be able to configure Eclipse to stop validating the file.

There are two ways to implement #4:

- You can ignore the resource. That makes this file invisible to Eclipse and all plugins. Which means you can't edit it anymore inside of Eclipse. Use [Resource Filters](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fresourcefilters.htm) for that.
- You can check the per-project preferences for Validation rules for JavaScript. Maybe you can exclude the file.

Comment: Thank you for the summary. I'll hold out a little to see if there's a better option.     1. I was hoping to not have to ignore the error.   2. I can't change the extension at present (.js is expected by the LightCouch library).  3. I wasn't able to delete the error- It doesn't show in the Error view. I will look for a way to do this though.       I'll accept this if a better solution doesn't come through.

Comment: @StevenR.Loomis I found another option: Try to configure per-project JavaScript validation and exclude the file.

Comment: thanks. What is working for me is using a regex to remove the name 'anonymous' and convert from this form, that way I still get validation:  function anonymous(doc) {
   if(doc.somekey) emit(doc._id, doc);
 }